# Laravel Blade Templating + Vue2 HTML Render

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

Tengo una aplicación que utiliza `Laravel 5.4` y a modo de realizar búsquedas de registros de modo reactivo con `AJAX` decidí utilizar `Vue 2.`

El tema es que al renderizar la información de `Vue.js` me aparece el clásico y lógico error de `Laravel`, que no encuentra la constante:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container" id="app">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form method="GET" class="form" action="" id="search-ads" @submit.prevent="submitForm">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar" v-model="term">
                   <select class="form-control" v-model="category">
                        <option value="" selected disabled>Categor&iacute;a</option>
                        @forelse(App\Category::all() as $category)
                        <option value="{!! $category->id !!}">{!! $category->name !!}</option>
                        @empty
                        <option value="" selected disabled>No hay categor&iacute;as</option>
                        @endforelse
                    </select>
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
              </span>
            </div>
            </form>         
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <ul class="ads">
                <li v-for="ad in ads">
                    @{{ ad.id }} <-- Error
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var vm = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            term: "",
            category: "",
            ads: []
        },
        methods: {
            loadAds: function() {
                axios.get('{{ url('/api/get') }}', {
                    params: {
                        term: this.term,
                        category: this.category
                    }
                }).then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + error);
                });
            },
            submitForm: function() {
                if(this.term != '' || this.category != '') {
                    this.loadAds();
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Error:**
[image: Error Laravel 5.4]

He probado como varios sitios dicen que con `@{{ ad.id }}` ignora la variable de Laravel y es verdad, pero en cambio se muestra puro el HTML `{{ ad.id }}` y ningún valor de Vue.js

¿Alguna sugerencia para ignorar la sintáxis de Blade y mostrar el componente Vue o tal vez una directiva `v-` que permita mostrar ese contenido sin utilizar llaves dobles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creería que no es necesario que utilices jQuery y su `$(document).ready(function() {........});`, no lo necesita Vue para ejecutarse, por lo tanto puedes eliminar ese "wrapper" .

En cuanto a Vue, la sintaxis es correcta, lo probé con las mismas variables y todo funciona, incluso poniendo valores "dummy":

```
<li v-for="ad in ads">
    @{{ ad.id }}
</li>
```

Lo único que se me ocurre es que **no compilaste los assets con webpack** una vez hiciste la modificación.

Comment: Gracias por contestar, aún así, estoy estudiando sobre eso que decís, que no compilé los assets con webpack.

Comment: Finalmente pudiste resolver tu problema? si mi respuesta te sirvió (teniendo en cuenta que fue la primera), puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Como comenté en la respuesta siguiente, tengo otro problema, por lo que mi problema original está intacto, o perdió prioridad. Quise instalar npm en Ubuntu y desinstaló Plesk :/ Apenas pueda probar la marcaré como correcta si me sirvió más que la anterior.

Comment: Hola, aunque compilé los assets creo, esa sintáxis nunca me funcionó ya que mostraba `{{ ad.id }}` y no realizaba ninguna acción, ahora después de compilar, me muestra un error de nginx!!

Comment: Aparentemente ya lo hice, pero sigue pasando lo mismo, me aparece textualmente `{{ ad.id }}` y no su contenido

Comment: La verdad es muy raro, yo lo probé en un proyecto que estoy haciendo, lo modifiqué un poco con la misma información que tienes (también uso axios), y me funciona sin problema.

Comment: Me fijé en las herramientas de desarrollo de Firefox y me muestra la llamada AJAX con su respectiva respuesta, pero a la hora de mostrar la información con `@{{ ad.id }}` me muestra `{{ ad.id }}` y si llego a usar sin el @, me aparece un error de PHP que me dice que se asumió "ad" como una constante.

Answer (score 1):

Creeria que la linea del document ready de jquery te esta sobrando, prueba sin esa linea y deja que la parte del javascript comience desde:

```
var vm = new Vue ({ ...
```

En caso de que no hallas compilado los assets con webpack utiliza:

```
npm install
```

Con eso instalas los paquetes que necesitas incluido vue y webpack, luego para que compiles los assets:

```
npm run watch
```

Recuerda agregar el script de vue por si no lo tienes adicionado. 
Suerte

Comment: Me mandé una macana y borré Plesk gracias a instalar npm jaja... Ahora mi problema es otro, no puedo marcar ninguna respuesta como correcta porque no tengo cómo probar. Muchas gracias por comentar, apenas lo resuelva (si puedo) y pruebo.

Comment: Ahora obtengo éste error, después de `npm run watch` y hayan salido un montón de errores: https://i.imgur.com/Q8Su4K9.png